# Use persian footnotes inside latin environment of xepersian

Tags: footnotes, xepersian, persian

When I'm inside `latin` environment, I'm unable to change footnote mark from **Arabic** style to **Persian**(*Arabic-Indic*) style.

Here is the code I use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

%packages:
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx, float}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{xepersian}
% fonts
\settextfont{HM FElmi}
\setlatintextfont{FreeSerif}
\defpersianfont\Bismillah[Scale=14]{A_Bismillah}
\setpersiansansfont[Scale=1]{HM FElmi}

\begin{document}
سلام
\footnote{
    در این جا مشکلی وجود ندارد
}
\vspace{\fill}
\begin{latin}
Translate
\RTLfootnote{ترجمه}
\end{latin}
\end{document}
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the second footnote mark is in *Arabic* style which is not desired. How can I change it to *Persian* style?

I think of some commands such as `\roman{}`, `\arabic{}` and so on, does any such command exists in `XePersian` package to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct behavior, and how footnotes (and footnote marks) should be typeset. If, however, for any reason you want the "2" to be Persian, you could write:

```
\begin{latin}
Translate\rl{\footnotemark}
\RTLfootnotetext{ترجمه}
\end{latin}
```

or simply:

```
\begin{latin}
Translate\rl{\RTLfootnote{ترجمه}}
\end{latin}
```

and if you want every footnote mark to be Persian, redefine @makefnmark

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\rl{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}}%
\makeatother
```